# Riddle - who am I - when you

Tags: riddle

> When you kill me, I return stronger.
>
> When you die, I live on.

**Who am I?**

Only specific thing is that, we have occured that riddle inside the ancient (like aztec) pyramid in D&D game. It has no connection with what could possibly happen in game (as far we could know). The last riddle answer was shine (on another reflection, NOT THIS ONE)

Comment: This is too broad, can you edit to make it more specific?

Comment: I dont have any more specific text. It has been occured by me and my team during D&D roleplay and after we try a few ideas then we can gain a correct one (we are out of any more ideas) from GM (after a successfull try out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a few things...

When you kill me, I return stronger

> Hope -- You can kill hope for a short time, but then it usually starts up again even stronger
>
> Dreams -- Same as hope, if your dream gets killed normally the desire to achieve it will come back even stronger.
>
> Weeds -- at least for me, whenever I try to pull up all the weeds or plants (like 4 o'clocks, they just won't go away!), they seem to be dead and gone for a short time and then even more pop up.
>
> Virus -- people create vaccinations and medicine to kill and combat viruses in peoples bodies and it works, but sometimes viruses use the antibodies found and they mutate and adapt to it and come back stronger in different strains.

When you die, I live on.

> Your hope and dreams can live on in other people that you touch, and viruses and weeds live on without you.

Comment: I was told by GM that the answer was: "Immortal" 
Thank you for brilliant ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention D&D I suspect that you are referring to :

> Your D&D avatar...
>  When it is killed it usually comes back with a new set of capabilities
>  When you die (that is: You the person) it (that is: It the avatar) lives on.

Comment: I was told by GM that the answer was: "Immortal" 
Thank you for brilliant idea :)